How to manually unwind the stack with RtlUnwind without using exceptions or error handling
I'm looking to unwind the stack conditionally and at a predetermined number of layers.
doing this with RtlUnwind gives one of two errors depending on how you use it.

A malformed function table was encountered during an unwind operation

#include <windows.h>

HANDLE consoleHandle;

void MyFunction()
{
    WriteConsoleW(consoleHandle, L"Inside MyFunction\n", 18, NULL, NULL);
}

void UnwindOneLayer(void* EstablisherFrame)
{
    WriteConsoleW(consoleHandle, L"Unwinding one layer\n", 20, NULL, NULL);
    RtlUnwind(EstablisherFrame, NULL, NULL, 0);
}

int main()
{
    consoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    WriteConsoleW(consoleHandle, L"Before calling MyFunction\n", 26, NULL, NULL);
    MyFunction();
    WriteConsoleW(consoleHandle, L"After calling MyFunction\n", 25, NULL, NULL);

    UnwindOneLayer(&main);

    WriteConsoleW(consoleHandle, L"After unwinding\n", 25, NULL, NULL);
    return 0;
}


An invalid or unaligned stack was encountered during an unwind operation

#include <windows.h>

HANDLE consoleHandle;

void MyFunction()
{
    WriteConsoleW(consoleHandle, L"Inside MyFunction\n", 18, NULL, NULL);
}

void UnwindOneLayer(void* EstablisherFrame)
{
    WriteConsoleW(consoleHandle, L"Unwinding one layer\n", 20, NULL, NULL);
    RtlUnwind(EstablisherFrame, NULL, NULL, 0);
}

int main()
{
    consoleHandle = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    void* fakeFrame = _alloca(1);

    WriteConsoleW(consoleHandle, L"Before calling MyFunction\n", 26, NULL, NULL);
    MyFunction();
    WriteConsoleW(consoleHandle, L"After calling MyFunction\n", 25, NULL, NULL);

    UnwindOneLayer(fakeFrame);

    WriteConsoleW(consoleHandle, L"After unwinding\n", 25, NULL, NULL);
    return 0;
}

I don't even know what these errors mean, let alone how to fix them

Have you aligned it correctly to the address before importing table? Same as how did you use RtlAddFunctionTable before RtlUnwind? You should provide a minimal reproducible example to make community better find and solve your problems.

@Torrecto-MSFT adding now

It's by design. When all the exception callback functions in the program do not handle the exception, RtlUnwind will have the system call all registered callback functions in the thread where the exception occurred before terminating the program. It is usually used in conjunction with GetExceptionInformation, e.g. __except (filter(GetExceptionInformation())), filter contains EXCEPTION_POINTERS structure.

But i tested your code they both return the first error. You can see the third parameter EXCEPTION_RECORD, the exception code is not meant to be handled by applications. It is raised only for the benefit of the debugger, and is raised only when a debugger is attached to the console process.

@Torrecto-MSFT what should I use instead?

do you have a working example of RtlUnwind being used without seh?

The old doc show how to make seh program: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/ya79k5zx(v=vs.110) Also, I have a former thread solved by op himself, he used another thing alternative: https://github.com/d366/DarkMMap/blob/master/Process.cpp#L173

If the github link is not what your want and the SEH is inevitable.

Any ideas on this alternative or other questions?

I didn't see the function RtlUnwind being used in the code in the github repo. I'm confident that this is possible to do without SEH, at least it seems that way from the microsoft docs. Perhaps MS has internal testbench code you can look for?

If you can prove it's not possible, you can post that as an answer and I'll accept it

Sorry for the delay. Indeed it is possible just for exceptions and stack Unwinding. RtlUnwind is designed to restore the execution state of the program, jumping to the position before the exception occurred. Check it if it is what your want: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/exceptions-and-stack-unwinding-in-cpp?view=msvc-170

@Torrecto-MSFT your wording was somewhat unclear. Are you saying that what I am attempting to do is not possible?

RtlUnwind may be impossible. Because the former doc, blog and code are all deleted.(I don't know why). So for unwinding the stack, you need to find something else like: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/exceptions-and-stack-unwinding-in-cpp?view=msvc-170 or just uisng __try{}/__except{} without it. I've already tried using RtlUnwind in __except{} but it does'not work.
